# Xpath - Select nodes by searching following siblings

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a xml like this,

```
<chap>
    <p>aaa</p>
    <h1>bbb</h1>
    <p>ccc</p>
    <p>ddd</p>
    <h1>eee</h1>
    <p>fff</p>  
    <h2>ggg</h2> 
    <p>hhh</p> 
    <h1>iii</h1> 
    <p>jjj</p> 
    <h1>kkk</h1> 
    <p>lll</p> 
    <h1>mmm</h1> 
    <p>nnn</p> 
    <h2>ooo</h2> 
    <h1>ppp</h1>
    <p>qqq</p>
</chap>
```

I need to select `h1` nodes which when going down the xml tree first following-sibling h node find is `h1` node. if first finding following-sibling is `h2` that `h1` should not be selected.

so above xml

```
<h1>bbb</h1>
<h1>iii</h1>
<h1>kkk</h1>
```

nodes should be selected.

How can I write a xpath query to select above nodes from xml?

```
Xpath version is 2.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is one possible XPath 1.0 compatible expression :**

```
/chap/h1[following-sibling::*[starts-with(name(),'h')][1][self::h1]]
```

**brief explanation :**

- `/chap/h1` : find all `h1` that is direct child of the root element `chap`
- `following-sibling::*[starts-with(name(),'h')][1]` : find the nearest following sibling element having `name()` starts with `h`...
- `[self::h1]` : ... and the found element is `h1`